# Anylogic Event Loop Exception

Tags: anylogic

I recently started studying Anylogic with everything and ran into the following problem.

After adding a material object, when trying to resize it using the properties panel, Anylogic throws the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNqWj.png)
Anylogic version 8.8.5 Personal Learning Edition.

I tried to do it on different models. Reinstalled anylogic.

Comment: Its a known bug with 8.8.5. Uninstall and install 8.8.4.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ive also encountered this problem in 8.8.6.
For anyone who gets this error, try to reinstall AnyLogic this way:

1. Uninstall it through programs and features
2. Go to c:/program files x86/ and delete anylogic folder
3. Go to c:/users/user_name/ and delete .AnyLogicPLE folder (it is hidden by default)
4. Finally go to regedit, ctrl+f anylogic and delete most of the entries (honestly, i dont know if it necessary, but ive done it and it worked). I didnt only delete entries in AppListBackup/
5. Restart your PC

Then install AnyLogic the usual way.